# php page accessible only by passing through another php page

Tags: php, security

I am looking to develop a website containing stages. I want for example to pass by the stage 2 only when i click on the finish button in the page of stage 1 so the stage 2 page  can't be accessible by its url or whatever only if the user  pass by another page.

Is there a method to do this ??? i am a beginner in security so please try to help me, thanks in advance coders

Comment: Look up "PHP tokens", that may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [`sessions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to develop this model.

**`index.php`**

```
<?php
@extract($_POST);
if(isset($sub))
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['authenticate']=true;
    header("location:test1.php");
    exit;
}
?>
<form action='' method="post">

    <input type="SUBMIT" name="sub" value="Finish" />

</form>
```

**`open.php`**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['authenticate']))
{
    echo "You are not allowed to access";
}
else { echo "You came from index.php ! so you are a valid user"; }
session_destroy(); //<-- I added this so you can test your example multiple times.
```

Comment: i entered the url of the open.php it gave me you came from index.php ... is there a way taht if i click on a button in index.php it will let me go the open.php otherwise is there no way to do it ? sorry if i am disturbing you but i really need a help in this

Comment: If you directly enter `open.php` you will get the message `You are not allowed to access`. Maybe you can accidentally accessed `index.php` before.

Comment: Exit should be called when entering the loop for authentication not set, it would stop the script from processing anything beyond

Comment: Or even call a location header for a forced redirect back to the required page

Comment: do i leave the action in the form empty ?

Comment: @DarylGill, That's right. user335... just try the example as it is .. Its tested already.

Comment: @user3359695, The action method is used to forward the `posted` entities over to the new page. With a blank action, the form will just POST to it's self

Comment: great it worked. one other question; can hackers hack the stage 2 for example and enter the page without passing by stage 1 page ? or its 100% secure ?

Comment: **100% secure as I know of.** Because sessions are resident on the server , not on the client.

Comment: Really thank u man , i appreciate it from you . so now i can use it in all my stages thank u again

Comment: if i remove session destroy it wont work anymore right? what if i refresh the page , it gave me the error is there a way to solve it?

Comment: "You are not allowed to access" , what if the user refresh it? he should reenter stage 1 and do it ?

Comment: Yeah that's what.. The `session_destroy()` should not be there. It should be used when you are implementing a logout feature. I just showed it for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this show work :)

Use can either redirect your user directly from index.php to open.php

```
header('Location : open.php');
```

Or,
in open.php, put this

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'index.php page's full link') {
  //Do or Show whatever you want to show here
} else {
  // Tell the user that you are not authorized
}
```

If that doesn't work, echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and see what link it gives you. And put that link where specified above.

Cool? :)

Edit (As per the comments) --

Lets say you have a form in your form in stage1.php

```
<form method="post" action="">
<span class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></span>
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

use this php in stage1.php

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])||isset($_POST['email'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST["name"])||!empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $error = "Please fill in all the fields correctly";
    }
    else {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        //You can also save the above Variables Globally by $GLOBALS['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        //So that you can use the details when you reach the final stage
        header('Location : stage2 page's link');
    }   
}
?>
```

and in Page 2 lets say you have another form, then there also check

```
<?php
if(!empty($name)||!empty($email)) { 
//the above is check for global variables email and name are not empty - means stage 2 was filled properly

//Do things for the second page's form like you did for stage 1
} else {
header('Location : stage1 page's link');
//redirect back to stage 1. 
}
?>
```

Comment: This method is a bit unreliable because the HTTP referrer can be spoofed.

Comment: i am making a website containing stages so i want the user to enter stage 2 the moment he clicks the button finish in the page of stage 1 , thats what i want .. can you help me in this ?

Comment: for click events you need to use javascript. In your button add the attribute `onclick="javascript:rtostage2();"` and then in your page's head, make a script tag and inside it put `function rtostage2() { window.location="Link to stage 2's page "; }` 

Done :)

Comment: is there a way for hackers to hack and enter stage 2 ? or its secure 90%?

Comment: See, For better security what you can do, validate all fields in the form and check them if they are empty and set or not. You want me to write the code for that in the answer above? :P

Comment: uff if you can do it you're going to save my life for sure , but if you don't have time its okay i try to figure it out alone:p

Comment: Done... Thats all basic, i hope you can do the rest yourself. Can't write everything. Not much time :)